Show that the domain of Legendre transformation $g$ can be a point, a closed interval, or a ray if $f$ is defined on the whole $x$ axis (Arnol'd)
This question is from Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics (Arnol'd) page 62. A great deal of the machinery of the Legendre transform is given immediately before this question, so I went for what I hope is a clean proof that doesn't define an excess of terms.

The function $f \subset \mathbb R^2$ is convex and defined over the entire real line. The function $g$ is the Legendre transformation of $f$.
Show that the domain of $g$ can be a point, a closed interval, or a ray.

We'll build the proof for the ray, using the cases for the point and closed interval as stepping stones towards our goal.
For any real number $y > \inf f$, there exists some $f(x) = y$. We'll state (without loss of generality) that the minimum point of $f$ is either on or to the right of the origin.
The Domain is a Point:
Choose any $p \in \mathbb R$, so long as $p$ is the slope of a line $l \subset \mathbb R^2$ that passes through the origin and two points of $f$. We know from Arnol'd that we can have $g(p) = \sup(f-l)$. Therefore $g$ can be defined on this point.
The Domain is a Closed Interval:
Choose any $p' > p$ and have the closed interval $[p, p']$. We can create a new line $l'$ that also passes through the origin and has slope $p'$. The minimum point of $f$ is at or to the right of the origin, so we know that $l_{p'}$ will also pass through two points of $f$. This gives a similar map $g(p') = \sup(f- l')$. By continuity, any value between $p$ and $p'$ will induce a similar line through the origin and two points of $f$. Therefore $g$ can be defined on this closed interval.
The Domain is a Ray:
We can make $p'$ as arbitrarily high as we want, and the line $l'$ which passes through the origin will still pass through two points of $f$. As a result, no matter how high we set $p'$, we can return a real-valued $g(p') = \sup (f - l')$. Thus $g$ can be defined on the ray $[p, \infty)$.
If the minimum point of $f$ is instead to the left of the origin, then simply make $p' < p$ for the interval and the ray, and repeat the proof.
QED.

Can I build up to the ray case using the point and closed interval cases like I did? Was my execution of the strategy sufficient? Thanks in advance!
